# Internet Explorer CSS class style doesn't apply if there are other element with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I have a problem that haunts me almost a week now!!

This is the scenario,

I have 6 step tabs, step 1 tab, step 2 tab, and so on..
I have a css class named "locked" and "active".

"**locked**" - it has a style `top: 3em;` which causes the tab to go down a little bit then I have some element that will block it so the tab will hide at the back of that element then that's why it's locked.

"**active**" - it has a style `top: 0em;` which cause the tab to go up then it will become visible so you can now click the tab.

Now, I have an event on my javascript code. If that event triggers, I will add the class "active" and remove the class "locked" using jQuery. `$("#step1").addClass("active").removeClass("locked");`

So that particular step will become active or visible(in my example step 1), then the others are not visible. So now the elements that have a class **locked** are the step 2, step 3 to step 6.

Then the event will trigger to another step and so on.. up to step 6. 
Then all step will become visible.

This is working on chrome and mozilla but not on IE

On internet explorer, even if the class **locked** is removed and I added the class **active**, the style will not apply, why? because there are other steps with a class **locked**. It will only become visible if there are no other step tab with a class name **locked**. So for short, all step tab will become visible after the class **locked** is removed on the last step.

**EDIT:**

This is my html code

```css
.step_tab.locked {
  color: #797979;
  cursor: default;
  top: 3em;
}
.step_tab.active {
  background: #54B848;
  cursor: default;
  top: 0em;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="step_tab step1 active"><span class="step_label">Step</span> <span class="digit_label">1</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="step_tab step2 locked"><span class="step_label">Step</span> <span class="digit_label">2</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="step_tab step3 locked"><span class="step_label">Step</span> <span class="digit_label">3</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="step_tab step4 locked"><span class="step_label">Step</span> <span class="digit_label">4</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="step_tab step5 locked"><span class="step_label">Step</span> <span class="digit_label">5</span></a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

If you noticed, all step_tab is locked. Then event triggers, which I will add and remove class on the step_tab. By inspecting the DOM pressing F12, the jQuery addClass and removeClass is working. The only problem is even if I removed the class **locked** and changed it to **active** let's say for example step1, it will not apply on that because the IE can see another element with the same parent element with a class **locked**

Comment: can you share whole css class definition of `locked`? and which IE version?

Comment: `.step_tab.locked {
 color: #797979;
 cursor: default;
 top: 3em;
}`

Comment: `.step_tab.active {
 background: #54B848;
 cursor: default;
 top: 0em;
}`

Comment: Please at least post some of the code you are using.

Comment: IE version 10 and greater. Since I restrict the user from accessing the page if he/she is browsing using IE 9 and lower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. 
I have class

`.step_tab {
    display: block;
}`

I just changed the display to **inline-block** annnnddd I don't know it just solved my problem xD